# Install flask with pycharm and app engine

Tags: python, google-app-engine, flask, pycharm

I'm using pycharm (4.0.1) on windows, I created a new app engine project, tested, project ran.

In project settings I added a virtual environment where I installed flask. Everything seems to be fine, interpreter points to my virtual environment and when I start typing in pycharm `from flask import Flask` it autocompletes import.

When I run project it's buildt with no errors. But when I access a page in a browser I get the following error:

```
File "C:\GAP\myproject\main.py", line 1, in <module>
    from flask import Flask
ImportError: No module named flask
```

Does anyone know what's the problem?

P.S. ** I followed instructions on https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=FRI3QGNWJYI **

Comment: How can you avoid doing this every time you open up a new Project that requires Flask?

Answer (score 18, accepted):

Windows Pycharm, you can go to `File->Settings->Project interpreter`, click the green `+` button (Install), type in flask, select `Flask` from the list then click `Install Package`. After installation, you will get the message saying flask installed successfully. You can rerun the project.

Answer (score 3):

Simply type the command `pip install flask` in your terminal

Answer (score 1):

have you ran

```
pip install flask
```

also to use flask with google app engine on production environment , you will have to place the flask folder within your project (e.g in a `lib/` folder) and add it to the system path in the `appengine_config.py` like this:

`sys.path.insert(0, os.path.join(os.path.dirname(__file__), 'lib'))`